# Can I [safely] change the code name/EntityPropertyName of objects?

Tags: list, powershell, column, client-object-model

We have several lists and columns that we've renamed overtime, and some of the lists/columns also contain spaces. This makes accessing these objects with the `EntityProperytName` through the CSOM quite annoying.

i.e. to access our list "Line Of Business", the code is `Line_x0020_of_x0020_Business`.

In hindsight, I'd create these objects with no spaces.

Through PowerShell, or some other way, is it possible to change the EntityPropertyName of these objects without breaking SharePoint? I don't care if our custom code breaks, since we've just started development and have very little (almost none).

*SharePoint 2013 on-premise.*

Comment: @404 yea, i was hoping on changing the internal name.

Comment: 404, you need to put that as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood your question, you want to change internal name of columns.Please correct me if i am wrong. But i am afraid, you cannot change the internal name of columns once it is created. Internal Name property is read only. You have to delete the column and recreate in that case.